# Back Button Not Working when implemented a ListView Builder Widget Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have this code which displays a back button, text, and then a listview builder widget.

When I remove the listview builder widget, the back button works fine, but when I add it back the back button breaks. I don't know why this is happening and need this issue to be fixed pretty quickly. Thanks!

Here's the code for the screen (everything works perfectly so the other screens passing in data are not included):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workout_app/Screens/Components/Sign_Up_Screens/screen2.dart';

class SingleSelectListViewWithLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  const SingleSelectListViewWithLogo({Key? key, required this.items}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SingleSelectListViewWithLogoState createState() =>
      _SingleSelectListViewWithLogoState();
}

class _SingleSelectListViewWithLogoState extends State<SingleSelectListViewWithLogo> {
  int? selectedIndex;

  void returnScreen(context) {
    print('returning');
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        fullscreenDialog: true,
        builder: (context) => screen2(),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool nextValid = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Material(
      child: Container (
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
        height: size.height,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget> [
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * .06,
              left: size.width * .03,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  returnScreen(context);
                },
                child: Image.asset(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  "assets/images/back2.png",
                  width: size.width * .07,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * .09,
              left: size.width * .4,
              child: const Text(
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 3, 3)),
                'Goals'
              )
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * .15,
              left: size.width * .07,
              child: const Text(
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 48, 48)),
                'What body type do you want to get?'
              )
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * .26,
              left: size.width * .4,
              child: const Text(
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 31, 31)),
                'Select 1'
              )
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: widget.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                      nextValid = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: size.height * .15,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: selectedIndex == index ? Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 188, 72) : Color.fromARGB(255, 202, 195, 195),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: selectedIndex == index ? Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 66, 37) : Colors.transparent,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, index == 0 ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.265 : 0, 16, 8),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(widget.items[index]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * .86,
              left: size.width * .1,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: size.width * .8,
                height: size.height * .08,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(                  
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(!nextValid ? Color.fromRGBO(69, 75, 85, 1) : Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 147, 246)),
                  ),
                  child: const Text('Continue',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using `Stack` widget everywhere, even when you're rendering the `ListView.builder`. When this is the case, the `ListView.builder` covers the whole screen, especially when not given a bounded height/width. In that case since everything is in a `Stack`, based on how you write the widgets inside it, some of them stay on top while others will stay on the bottom, therefore not tappable. If I were to rewrite this implementation I would go with a `Column` and it would be like the following:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Material(
        child: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
          height: size.height,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  onTap: returnScreen,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.back_hand),
                ),
                const Text(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 3, 3)),
                    'Goals'),
                const Text(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 48, 48)),
                    'What body type do you want to get?'),
                const Text(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 31, 31)),
                    'Select 1'),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: widget.items.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                            nextValid = true;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: size.height * .15,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: selectedIndex == index
                                ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 188, 72)
                                : const Color.fromARGB(255, 202, 195, 195),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: selectedIndex == index
                                  ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 66, 37)
                                  : Colors.transparent,
                              width: 3,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                              16,
                              index == 0
                                  ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.265
                                  : 0,
                              16,
                              8),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Flexible(
                                child: Text(widget.items[index]),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: size.height * .86,
                  left: size.width * .1,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: size.width * .8,
                    height: size.height * .08,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                            !nextValid
                                ? const Color.fromRGBO(69, 75, 85, 1)
                                : const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 147, 246)),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Continue',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ])),
    ));
  }
```

But if you're adamant in using a `Stack` instead of `Column` this is how you should go with it:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
        height: size.height,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
                top: size.height * .09,
                left: size.width * .4,
                child: const Text(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 4, 3, 3)),
                    'Goals')),
            Positioned(
                top: size.height * .15,
                left: size.width * .07,
                child: const Text(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 48, 48)),
                    'What body type do you want to get?')),
            Positioned(
                top: size.height * .26,
                left: size.width * .4,
                child: const Text(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 31, 31)),
                    'Select 1')),
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: widget.items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                      nextValid = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: size.height * .15,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: selectedIndex == index
                          ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 188, 72)
                          : const Color.fromARGB(255, 202, 195, 195),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: selectedIndex == index
                            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 66, 37)
                            : Colors.transparent,
                        width: 3,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        16,
                        index == 0
                            ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.265
                            : 0,
                        16,
                        8),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(widget.items[index]),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * .86,
              left: size.width * .1,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: size.width * .8,
                height: size.height * .08,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(!nextValid
                        ? const Color.fromRGBO(69, 75, 85, 1)
                        : const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 147, 246)),
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Continue',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {},
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * .06,
              left: size.width * .03,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  returnScreen(context);
                },
                child: Image.asset(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  "assets/images/back2.png",
                  width: size.width * .07,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Notice how I put the `InkWell` as the last child of the Stack, so it stays at the top and becomes tappable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked perfectly! I went with the second option because for the first (Column) option the positioning wasn't right and I didn't know how to position text in a column. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Nice to hear this helped you. Flutter layouts sometimes want you to fiddle around, but it's easy to solve as you see :).

Comment: Yeah! I do have one more issue I am wrestling with - which I posted just now. It would be great if you could help me with it! But no worries if you can't as that issue isn't urgent. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the thread over there. Hopefully that'll solve your issue.

Comment: Alright Bqubique I have one more question I posted - this one is a little more complicated but still really simple - I just don't know how to do it. It would be great if you could check it out. Thanks!